# Language is different than it's supposed to be

Tags: arch-linux, locale, language

I want my computer's language to be English and everything else to be finnish. Problem is that my computer's language is finnish now too. My guess is that LC_ALL is overriding the LANG part. I'm using arch if that helps.

Output of locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fi_FI.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=fi_FI.UTF-8
```

Comment: `LC_ALL` does indeed override everything. Do you know where that's set? Unset it

Comment: @roaima I dont know where it's set. /etc/locale.conf doesnt have LC_ALL.

Comment: Not familiar with Arch but `grep -rl LC_ALL /etc` may help

Comment: Ah yes, there was a sneaky LC_ALL in /etc/environment. Thank you @roaima!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LC_ALL` does indeed override everything. I'm not familiar with Arch but `grep -rl LC_ALL /etc` may help.

A comment then responds,

> Ah yes, there was a sneaky `LC_ALL` in `/etc/environment`

Removing this should allow the system to function with English language message but the Finnish locale for everything else.